# Testing with RxJs TestScheduler

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, react-redux, observable, redux-observable

I come from Java background & struggling to use RxJs TestScheduler.

Here is sample code that I want to test:

```
export const getData = action$ => action$.ofType(ACTIONS.APP.DATA.REQUEST)
    .mergeMap(() => restGet('<some-url>')         
    ).<some-observable>
```

where `restGET` is making an HTTP call and I have to mock it using `inject-loader`, same with retryWithDelay.

I tried following:

```
 const action$ = scheduler.createColdObservable(
            next(0, {type: ACTIONS.APP.DATA.REQUEST})
        );

        const data$ = app.getValue(ActionsObservable.of(action$));

        let actual = startScheduler(data$);

        const expected = [
            next(200, <someAction>),
            complete(200)
        ];

        expect(actual.messages).to.deep.equal(expected); // true
        expect(restGetSpy.calledOnce).to.be.true; // false
```

I'm able to inject dependencies in the code using `inject-loader`, and run the test using `testScheduler` but my mock restGetSpy doesn't get called seems like flow is not going inside mergeMap() but it's calling the end observable which raised success action and because of this am getting true on my first assert.

I am not able to understand why is this happening?

All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Unfortunately the provided code isn't complete enough to give you a solid answer, but what I can see suggests you might be using v4 of rxjs instead of v5 because the TestScheduler API you're using is most similar to v4? Can you perhaps distill the issue down to a very simple minimal reproduction without all the other unrelated stuff?

Comment: @jayphelps code updated. I'm able to inject dependencies in the code using inject-loader, and run the test using testScheduler but it seems my mock restGetSpy doesn't get called seems like flow is not going inside mergeMap() but its calling some observable which raised success action and because of this am getting true on first assert.